Как через winapi получать уведомления о подключении/отключении ethernet-кабеля
Собственно, стоит такая задача: написать приложение, которое должно висеть в системном трее и реагировать на подключение и отключение линка на сетевой карте компьютера. Подчеркну: программа должна реагировать именно на линк, а не наличие/отсутствие интернета или получение IP-адреса. Что конкретно она должна делать, не суть важно - пускай будет отображать сообщение о подключении или отключении витой пары с информацией о соответствующем адаптере (его имя, MAC-адрес, и т.п.).
Я понимаю себе весь процесс так: приложение при запуске должно как-то зарегистрировать себя в системе для получения уведомлений о событиях сетевого адаптера, после чего эти уведомления, собственно, получать и обрабатывать. Однако как всё это реализовать, совершенно не представляю (предполагаю, что через какие-то интерфейсы COM или OLE). Буду рад любым ссылкам на толковые статьи по данной теме и примеры рабочего кода.

Советую посмотреть на это, потом сюда и сюда. Я, если честно, не смог заставить это правильно работать. Точнее я смог получать уведомления, но интерпретировать верно их не вышло. Возможно, у вас получится. Вот пример кода, который получает уведомления: https://pastebin.com/LiJvcihY
